# とまで parsing and usage

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-と

In no game no life, this is one of the first things that is said about "blank", and it is supposed to translate to:

"Among gamers, they're said to be unbeatable.

勝｛か｝つことは不可能｛ふかのう｝とまで言われるゲーマーの話を‌ (cuts to next scene)

winning is impossible= 勝｛か｝つことは不可能｛ふかのう｝

get said gamer story=言われるゲーマーの話を‌

How does とまで link this together, and how is to grammatically correct here, and how do I parse this type of grammar consistently?

Comment: 「勝つことは不可能と言われるゲーマーの話」はわかります？(←without まで)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This まで (no. 4)](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/208999/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7/) is what is being used here.

In English, this would be translated in most cases as "even". と just is quoting what is 言われる. Without context, therefore, I would translate your phrase roughly as:

> The story of the gamer(s) (ゲーマーの話) (against whom)
>   people **even go so far as** (まで)
>   to say (言われる)
>   that winning is impossible (勝つことは不可能と)"

As far as を is concerned, without further context, we can only say for sure that it is marking the 'story' as an object for a verb, be it implied or explicit.